# How to avoid redeclaring props type in React constructor using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class PeopleByTag extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{ tag: string }>
```

I need to do something in my constructor, in this example fetch data, but to do that I need to declare a props parameter, but if I don't specify the type it will become any:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); // props is any
    this.loadData();
}
```

On the other hand, if I redeclare the type the code gets very ugly:

```
constructor(props: Readonly<{
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}> & Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{
    tag: string;
}, StaticContext, any>>) {
    super(props);
    this.loadData();
}
```

Is there a way to automatically infer the props type from the class extension while also being able to write a constructor?

I also don't want to use the deprecated lifecycle hooks (i.e. ComponentWillMount).

Comment: Isn't the recommended way to use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method for fetching data?

Comment: Also, calling methods from within the constructor is generally not best practice, as a subclass of the class can override methods but won't have had a chance to do their initialization before you call the method.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Depends on the case. Not necessarily an issue specifically for a method because prototype method can be overridden by a child. Also, the use of class inheritance is pretty much limited in React, in my experience.

Comment: @estus - Yes, in React components you're normally better off with aggregation or containment (certainly the React devs think so). But *in general*, it's not a good practice to get in the habit of.

Answer (score 3):

Usually `constructor` itself shouldn't get 'very ugly', just because types can be defined separately as `type` or `interface` in case parameter types are verbose.

Constructor `props` parameter cannot be inferred because `React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{ tag: string }>>` generic parameter refers to parent class, `React.Component`, not current class.

As it can be seen in [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/98787aca3728027c07640f0194b8ca5dded41ae4/types/react/index.d.ts#L284-L286), this infers proper type for parent constructor, i.e. `super`.

So this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

is valid. `this.props` is still properly typed.

In case `noImplicitAny` compiler option is used, it is:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
}
```

The use of `props` typed as `any` in constructor may result in type mistakes:

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    props.tag; // ok
    props.nonexistentProp; // ok
}
```

While `this.props` is type-safe.

A class can be typed with as generic to maintain proper props type in constructor, but this can be considered overkill:

```
export class PeopleByTag<P extends { tag: string }> extends React.Component<P> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<P>) {
    super(props); // props is any

    props.tag; // ok
    props.nonexistentProp; // not ok
    props.children; // not ok, but we rarely ever need children in constructor
  }
}
```

It may be beneficial to prevent the use of `props` in constructor by providing incompatible type for it:

```
constructor(props: never) {
    super(props);

    props.tag; // not ok
}
```

*If `props` argument was passed to `super`, `this.props` and `props` are interchangeable in JavaScript. They aren't interchangeable in TypeScript. `this.props` may be accessed in constructor for properly typed props.*

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend defining interfaces or type aliases to reduce the duplication, as estus said.  Note however that the type of the `props` parameter to the constructor can just be `Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{ tag: string }>>`, since the TypeScript compiler will automatically add the `children` property based on declarations in `@types/react` and you can rely on the defaults for the second and third type arguments to `RouteComponentProps`, just as you did in the extends clause.  (Arguably, if the parameter to the constructor is the real props object, then its type *should* include the `children` property and omitting the `children` property is bogus, but the omission is common practice and even appears in the declaration of the `React.Component` super constructor.  I've also omitted the `Readonly` in one project, but it seems that may no longer be recommendable.)  At that point, maybe you'll decide that the type is short enough that repeating it is OK and it's not worth defining an interface or type alias.

By the way, here's [the open suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911) for method and constructor parameter types to default to the types from the superclass.