# What is the correct way to access props in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, constructor

What is the correct way to access props in the constructor ? Yes i know that in the React documentation is said that

> When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, 
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs

To be more clear , why do wee need `this.props` if we can just use props inside constructor

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        console.log(props)
        // -> { something: 'something', … }
        // absolutely same
        console.log(this.props)
        // -> { something: 'something', … }
    }
}
```

Are there some cases when to use `props` over `this.props` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`this.props` and `props` are interchangeable in constructor because `this.props === props`, *as long as `props` is passed to `super`*. The use of `this.props` allows to detect a mistake instantly:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { foo: this.props.foo }; // this.props is undefined
}
```

Consistent use of `this.props` makes it easier to refactor constructor body:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { foo: this.props.foo };
}
```

to

```
state = { foo: this.props.foo };
```

Only `this.` needs to be removed.

There are also [typing problems with `props` in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803585/3731501), this makes `this.props` preferable for typed component.

Comment: Do you need to duplicate foo? It is not good idea holding the same object in state and props. Why?

Comment: @JaLe Because state may change independently from props. There's a need to set *initial* state, and sometimes it may depend on *initial* props in some way, they won't necessarily be same like in the example.

Comment: In this way it is true.

Comment: BUT be careful when you writing into this foo, you can change (mute) props.

Answer (score 5):

This recommendation exists to prevent you from introducing errors by calling other methods on the object from the constructor, which depend on `this.props`. You don't want to pass props to these explicitly.

E.g. the following would be a bug, because you call `doStuff` before `super`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        this.doStuff()
        super(props)
    }

    doStuff() {
      console.log("something is: " + this.props.something)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this , i have never called methods in constructor before. I just would like to know is there any difference between `props` and `this.props` in the constructor and which is the best choice ?

Comment: There is no difference

Answer (score 2):

> The correct way is - don`t use props in your constructor - just send into a parent.

But both way is working.

So, there is one special case for reading props in a constructor and it is set default state from props.

In a constructor after call `super(props)` are this.props and props **equals**. `this.props = props`.

Its only about what you prefer, I prefer call always `this.props`.

Example:

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           isRed: this.props.color === 'red',
        }
   }
```

Be sure, that you are calling `super(props)` on the first line in your constructor.

Comment: So if i want to set default state using props , how then should i act ?